# Find three prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, systems-of-equations

I have to find three prime numbers where, the product of them is equal to seven times of sum of them.

So I wrote the equation:

$x$-1st of them;

$y$-2nd;

$z$-3rd;

$xyz=7(x+y+z)$

${xyz\over 7}=x+y+z$

Where $x,y,z$ are prime numbers, so one of them must be $7$.

For example $x$

$yz=(7+y+z)$

Now I have to find these two numbers

I have found $5$ and $3$

$3*5*7=7(15)$

Which is correct.

My question is; Are there any other prime numbers, which 
meet the equation?

Comment: We have $7\mid xyz$, so that one of the primes $x,y,z$ is $7$. Without loss of generality, $x=7$. Then $yz=7+y+z$. However, very quickly $yz$ is bigger than $7+y+z$, and we are done.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote it, but a little differently ;)

Comment: I don't see where you write that we are done, not even a little differently:)

Comment: If
" ${xyz\over 7}=x+y+z $
Where x,y,z is prime number, so one of them must be 7."
is not the same as " We have  $ 7\mid xyz $ so that one of the primes x,y,z is 7." I would be blind...

Comment: Other fact; It is not the main topic of this question ;)

Comment: $yz=y+z+7$ is the same as $(y-1)(z-1)=8$

Comment: Fact, I didn't see this, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have concluded that we may assume that $pq=7+p+q$ and $p\le q$ for primes $p,q$. For $p\ge 7$ we see that $pq>p+q+7$. So it is enough to check the cases $p=2,3,5$. We see that the only solution is $p=3$ and $q=5$, up to permutation of $p$ and $q$.